# Why is my "vector subscript out of range"?

Tags: c++, vector, subscript

I am trying to make an algorithm that checks for duplicates. The algorithm takes in an integer `p` and aims to find the primitive root `g` if it satisfies that all values of g^x mod p (for values of x in the range of 0 to p - 2) are different.

I basically try to store all the values of g^x mod p in a vector and then I check for duplicates using a `digitsTable` vector that counts the frequency of each individual number. If the number is greater than 1, then it means there's a duplicate.

But the thing is, halfway through the algorithm, an error appears saying that the vector subscript is out of range. I did a bit of research and it refers to an accessing violation. I don't see where this is going wrong.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;

ll gcd(ll a, ll b) {
    ll r;

    while (b != 0) {
        r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}


int main()
{

    ll p;
    cin >> p;

    vector<ll> distinctIntegers;
    vector<ll> digitsTable;

    bool searching = true;
    

    ll g = 2;
    ll smallestRoot;
    ll rootCount = 1;

    while (searching) {
        bool primeRoot = true;
        distinctIntegers.push_back(1);

        for (ll x = 1; x <= p - 2; ++x) {
            distinctIntegers.push_back(g * distinctIntegers[x - 1] % p);
        }

        // fills a vector with zeroes
        for (ll i = 0; i < distinctIntegers.size(); ++i) {
            digitsTable.push_back(0);
        }

        // counts the frequency of each element in distinctIntegers.size()
        for (ll i = 0; i < distinctIntegers.size(); ++i) {
            ++digitsTable[distinctIntegers[i]];
        }
        
        
        for (ll i = 0; i < distinctIntegers.size(); ++i) {
            if (digitsTable[i] > 1) {
                primeRoot = false;
                ++g;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (primeRoot) {
            smallestRoot = g;
            searching = false;
        }
   
        //test
        distinctIntegers.clear();
        digitsTable.clear();
    }
    

    
    for (int m = smallestRoot; m <= p - 1; ++m) {
        if (gcd(m, p - 1) == 1) {
            rootCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << smallestRoot << " " << rootCount;
    
    
    return 0;
    
    // USED FOR TESTING
    /*
    * for (int i = 0; i < digitsTable.size(); ++i) {
            cout << digitsTable[i] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
        
    */
}
```

Comment: Is every element in `distinctIntegers` guaranteed to be a valid index into `digitsTable`?  Have you run your code in a debugger so you can examine what's going on?

Comment: Hi Stephen. I'm pretty sure. Should i update the comment and paste my entire code onto it? Edit: I have updated the entire code.

Comment: Shoot. I think I see what's the problem! That was very good insight you gave. Thanks!

Comment: OMG i fixed it. I had to update the input for digitsTable to ```distinctIntegers.size() + 1```!!